# Touch implementation in game

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, game-physics, xcode8, touches

I am using Swift 3 with Xcode 8 and I am trying to make simple game with SpritKit. Basically what I'm trying to do is allow player to move my sprite only left and right ( drag it on screen ) and after realising finger ( touch ended ) apply impulse on sprite. I have managed to do that BUT i want that to happen only on first touch, so after applying impulse on sprite player cannot interact with sprite anymore until some collison happens or simillar. Below is my code which works all the time not only on first touch.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {



}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches {

        let location = t.location(in: self)

        if player.contains(location)
        {
            player.position.x = location.x
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches {

        if let t = touches.first {

            player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
            player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 50))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing you need is a boolean variable, either on scene or on some your custom class, which will track if interaction is allowed. So after you apply impulse you set a boolean to false, and later in didBegin(contact:) you change that boolean accordingly.

Comment: I could add variable impulse set to one as default and allow user to interact with sprite only if variable impulse is > 0. After applying impulse set impulse to zero until did begin contact happens

Comment: Just use true and false. I mean 1 and 0 will work but no need for that. Or maybe you can use some of physicsBody's properties to determine if interaction is allowed. It really depends on how your game works and what suits best for you. But the bottom line is that this is simple task and can be done in many ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Whirlwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3402095/whirlwind) commented, you just need a boolean value to determine when you should control the object:

```
/// Indicates when the object can be moved by touch
var canInteract = true

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches {
        let location = t.location(in: self)
        if player.contains(location) && canInteract
        {
            player.position.x = location.x
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches {

        if let t = touches.first && canInteract {
            canInteract = false //Now we cant't interact anymore.
            player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
            player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 50))
        }
    }
}
/* Call this when you want to be able to control it again, on didBeginContact
   after some collision, etc... */
func activateInteractivity(){
    canInteract = true
    // Set anything else you want, like position and physicsBody properties
}
```